# how to make optional object parameter in Typescirpt?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have a function with following shape

```
const func = (arg1: string, { objArg = true }:{ objArg: string }) => { // some code }
```

i need to make second parameter (object) optional, is it possible ?

Comment: you cant use `objArg = true` as a boolean and define it as a string `objArg: string`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an empty object `{}` as default param value to it. Wrapping object param type with `Partial` to make its memebers optional, same as adding question mark `{ objArg?: string }`

```
const func = (arg1: string, { objArg = true }: Partial<{ objArg: string | boolean }> = {}) => {
  console.log(objArg)
}
```

Comment: does not seem to be working

Comment: I cannot identify what’s wrong in my solution. Would you enlighten me please, be specific about how does it not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can set an default value and it will be automatically optional:

```
const func = (
  arg1: string,
  { objArg = true }: { objArg: boolean } = undefined
) => {}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to make an parameter optional, you should use ?(question mark) before :
and optional parameter has to be the last parameter of function.
For more information check this page.
https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-optional-parameters/

Comment: i can make optional simple parameter but can not do it with objects

Comment: Can't you make an interface or type and assign that type to second parameter and make that optional.
For example: 
export interface MyObject{
objname?: object // Can be any type whatever you want 
}
Const funct =(arg1: string, arg2?: MyObject)=>{
// code